# How to create a record remotely, using rails json, ruby and bypassing sign-in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, httparty

I spent some time trying to understand how I could bypass my sign-in to create a record remotely recurring to json, without loosing the security provided by sign-in.
I managed to do this with HTTParty, but i guess rest-client would do as well.

I now share my solution, but i still think there probably are better and more safe ways to do this, and would like to hear your thoughts on this one.

So, first things first. Here is my controller :

things_controller.rb

```
...
before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:show, :destroy]
before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create], unless: :is_it_json?
...
def create
    if is_it_json?
      user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
      if !(user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password]))
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      else 
        @thing = user.things.build(params[:thing])
      end
    else
      @thing = current_user.things.build(params[:thing])
    end  
    respond_to do |format|
      if @thing.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, :flash => { :success =>  'thing was successfully created.'} }
        format.json { render json: @thing, status: :created, location: @thing}
      else
        @feed_items = []
        format.html { render action: "static_pages/home" }
        format.json { render json: @thing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
...
def is_it_json?
  request.format.json?
end
...
```

My ruby script: wsConsumption_httparty.rb

```
require 'HTTParty'
def ask(prompt)
    print prompt, ' '
    $stdout.flush
    s = gets.chomp 
end

class thingCreate
    include HTTParty
    base_uri 'localhost:3000'
    format :json
    headers "Accept" => "application/json"

  def initialize
  end

  def post(description, weight,typeid,email,password)
    options = { body: 
                {thing:
                    {description:description, 
                     weight:weight, 
                     type_id:typeid 
                     },
                session:
                    {email:email,
                    password:password
                    }
                }
            }
    self.class.post('/things', options)
  end
end

username = ask("What is the user email?")
password = ask("What's the password?")
description = ask("thing description: ")
weight = ask("Weight: ")
typeid = ask("Type Id: ")

thing = thingCreate.new()
print thing.post(description, weight,typeid,username,password)
```

This is working great to create...I would like to hear you on :

- How can this mechanism of creating a thing be safer (using https is
  enough?
- should i apply somekind of failsafe mechanism to the service? any
  suggestions?
- If the wrong user/pass is inserted, i would like to return a text message only saying "Invalid Username/Password"...any ideas on how i can achieve this?
- any other suggestion you might have.

Cheers

Comment: What was wrong with normal sign-in sequence? Why do you need to bypass it?

Comment: Hi, I need to bypass it because if I don't, when i try to create the record over json, i get redirected to the signin page. It is better i think to create an "embedded sign-in" within the service than to try and pass cookies around...(I have another post on the sign-in question though, that would like to know how to solve : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204591/remote-signin-not-working-with-httparty-and-restclient )